# Authenticate event delivery to event handlers (Azure Event Grid)

Tags: authentication, event-handling, bearer-token, azure-eventgrid

I want to let third-party organizations subscribe to my event grid events in a secure way. I am trying to do this using Azure AD as mentioned in the articles below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/secure-webhook-delivery

In the event subscription creation, I selected the WebHook endpoint type and entered the endpoint of the organization. For a proof of concept, I created an Azure Function (HttpTrigger) as a webhook endpoint out of my Azure AD.

[Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV8gI.png)

Under the Additional Feature tab, I activated AAD Authentication. In this way, I managed to send a bearer token to the webhook endpoint.

[AAD Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vtzL.png)

My question is that how should the event subscriber validate the token which is coming from the event publisher?

When you want to make a request to an API that is secured with a bearer token authentication, you would first request a token from the API, make your request with that token and the API validates it. In this scenario, the token issuer and validator are the same.

In the event publisher/subscriber scenario, the subscriber is not the token issuer. That's what confuses me.

When the token is decrypted, it is kind of obvious where it comes from.

```html
{
  "aud": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/",
  "iat": 1612970997,
  "nbf": 1612970997,
  "exp": 1613057697,
  "aio": "Lorem ipsum viverra",
  "appid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/",
  "oid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "rh": "Lorem ipsum viverra",
  "roles": [
    "role"
  ],
  "sub": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "tid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "uti": "Lorem ipsum viverra",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Should I just validate the token by having some constants about the event publisher or is there a more elegant way?

Update: In case anyone is interested in how I implemented it, I leave a demo project here.

https://github.com/sahinad/Event.Grid.Subscriber.Api

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did this. Very similar to the link you posted in your question, but I solved it using built-in Azure classes and needed to make some changes to have the `SubscriptionValidationEventData` object recognised correctly.

`EventsController.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace SamplesEventGridWebhooksAAD.Controllers
{
    public static class JsonExtension
    {
        public static bool TryParseJson<T>(this string @this, out T result)
        {
            bool success = true;
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Error = (sender, args) => { success = false; args.ErrorContext.Handled = true; },
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
            };
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(@this, settings);
            return success;
        }
    }
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class EventsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessEvent(List<EventGridEvent> eventGridEvents)
        {
            foreach (var eventGridEvent in eventGridEvents)
            {
                // If the contents of `eventGridEvent.Data` looks like `SubscriptionValidationEventData`, send the ValidationCode back as part of the response.
                // This is necessary for Event Grid to succesfully register the webhook.
                if (eventGridEvent.Data.ToString().TryParseJson(out SubscriptionValidationEventData eventData))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Got SubscriptionValidation event data, validationCode: {eventData.ValidationCode},  validationUrl: {eventData.ValidationUrl}, topic: {eventGridEvent.Topic}");
                    // Do any additional validation (as required) such as validating that the Azure resource ID of the topic matches
                    // the expected topic and then return back the below response
                    var responseData = new SubscriptionValidationResponse()
                    {
                        ValidationResponse = eventData.ValidationCode
                    };

                    return new OkObjectResult(responseData);
                }
            }

            return new OkObjectResult("The event has been processed.");
        }
    }
}
```

The pogram can be started up as follows:

`Program.cs`

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services
    .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()
    .AddHealthChecks();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapHealthChecks("/healthz");

app.Run();
```

We can use the following configuration:

`appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.com", // The "Primary domain" of your Azure AD Tenant
    "TenantId": "a9fxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
    "ClientId": "0f5xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx", // Output of `azuread_application.webhook.application_id`
    "Audience": "0f5xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx" // Output of `azuread_application.webhook.application_id`
  }
}
```